# Map Pie Charts in R on a US Map (Update, need to show categories)

Tags: r

EDIT: using scatterpie as suggested I can map my graphs but I can't get them to show different categories. Help would be appreciated. New code below. I think I'm close but I don't know how to get it to give me separate colors for each category

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(tidyverse)

# Load US map data
us_map <- st_as_sf(maps::map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))

regions_data <- list(
  Northeast = c("DE", "ME", "MD", "MA", "NJ", "CT", "NY", "PA"),
  OhioValley =  c("IL", "IN", "KY", "MO", "OH", "TN", "WV"),
  RockiesPlains = c("MT", "NE", "ND", "SD", "WY"),
  South = c("AR", "KS", "LA", "MS", "OK", "TX"),
  Northwest = c("WA", "OR", "ID"),
  Southwest = c("AZ", "CO", "NM", "UT"),
  West = "CA",
  Southeast = c("AL", "GA", "FL", "NC", "SC", "VA"),
  UpperMidwest =  c("IA", "MN", "WI", "MI")
)

mapping_df <- enframe(regions_data, name = "region", value = "state") %>%
  unnest(state) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(state.abb, state.name), by = c("state" = "state.abb")) %>%
  mutate(state.name = tolower(state.name))

us_map_regions <- left_join(us_map, mapping_df, by = c("ID" = "state.name"))

# Manually input data for scatter pie charts
scatterpie_data <- data.frame(
  region = c("Northeast", "Northeast", "Northeast", "OhioValley", "OhioValley", "OhioValley"),
  category = rep(c("Diploid", "Polyploid", "Unknown"), each = 2),
  value = c(30, 40, 30, 20, 30, 50),
  lon = c(-75, -75, -75, -90, -90, -90),
  lat = c(42, 42, 42, 38, 38, 38)
)

# Plot the map with scatter pie charts
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = us_map_regions, aes(fill = region)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "US Regions Map with Scatter Pie Charts", subtitle = "Customized Regions") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_sf_text(data = us_map_regions, aes(label = region), color = "black", size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = scatterpie_data, aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = category, size = value), alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 10)) +  # Adjust the size range as needed
  coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

Comment: Have you tries using `scatterpie`? I think it would do what you are trying to accomplish. Here are the docs: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html

Comment: I have not. I will give that a try.